# Чтение файла с web сервера

Tags: c#

Есть файл по адресу http://site.com/file1.txt. Как содержимое этого файла записать в переменную?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var client = new WebClient();
var stream = client.OpenRead("http://site.com/file1.txt");
var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
var content = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string content = GetContent("https://l24u.com/robots.txt");
}

public static string GetContent(string url)
{
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Proxy = null;
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.Timeout = 360000;
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
    {
        Stream requestStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        if (requestStream == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return new StreamReader(requestStream).ReadToEnd();
    }  
}
```